# How to get specific div text with jQuery filter()

Tags: jquery, filter, jquery-selectors

I have the following html that renders within an ASP.NET Repeater:

```
<div class="divDE-item" onclick="addFilter(this);">
  <span class="spnKey">Some key</span>
  <div>1234</div>
</div>
```

I realize that having an onclick on the outer div may not be the most graceful jQuery-centric approach. However, considering my situation, it works well.

Here is my addFilter() function:

```
function addFilter(oDiv) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Get and set the prefix text for the label. i.e. "Key = "
    sDEName = $(oDiv).find("span").text();
    $('#<%= lblDEName.ClientID %>').text(sDEName + " = ");

    // Get the actual filter text value. i.e. "1234"
    // sFilter = $(oDiv).text();
    var sFilter = $(oDiv).filter(function() {
        var filtered = $(this).not(".spnKey");
        return filtered
    });

    $('#<%= txtValue.ClientID %>').val(sFilter);
  });
}
```

The goal is for the output to appear like this (with 1234 being the value of a textbox):

**Some key = 1234**

However, the output I'm getting is: **Some key = Some key 1234**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to call `filter`.

You can simply write `$('div:not(.spnKey)', oDiv).text()`.

To answer your question, you're using `filter` and `not` wrong.  The `filter` method returns a jQuery object containing some of the elements in the one you call it on.  (Not their children).  To use it this way, you should call `$(oDiv).children().filter(...)`.

The `not` method is the opposite of `filter`, and returns the elements in the jQuery object that don't match a selector of function.  You could therefore also write `$(oDiv).children().not('.spnKey')`.

Comment: That worked! Thank you for the correction and example, very well put.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're going about this completely the wrong way.  Try this -- have your repeater spit out code as normal:

```
<div class="divDE-item">
  <span class="spnKey">Some key</span>
  <div>1234</div>
</div>
```

And use the following javascript to grab the value:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.divDE-item").click(function() { 
     $thisElement = $(this);
     var thisValue = $($thisElement).children("div").text();
     $('#<%= txtValue.ClientID %>').val(thisValue);
  });
});
```

This way it will apply that click event to every instance of that (I'm guessing repeated) div that appears in the DOM pre-render.  Should be a bit more lightweight as well.

Comment: I agree completely, and I tried that approach at first. I wasn't successful in getting the click event to fire. Perhaps it has something to do with the Repeater being within a ListView, all of which is within an UpdatePanel. The UpdatePanel being the likely culprit. So, I went with this admittedly less desirable approach with the onclick method. I'm all ears, though, for doing this the right way. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Very nice, that worked. I have not gotten around to checking out the new live() method. Thanks again!

Comment: @Clay: No problem.  `live()` isn't really a new method, and its a bit confusing in concept but can be very useful.  I just think of it as an event binder to objects that may appear in the DOM *after* $(document).ready()